# Stream from several android phones to pc

Tags: video, streaming, android

I'd like to know if there is a way to record from several android phones at the same time (at least 2) and send the data in real-time to a computer.

I don't need to watch the recording in real-time, just to save it. The idea is to use the computer as a server, so the phones are not storing anything.

Any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use streaming apps for android which transmit the screen to a desktop-machine from which you can capture the image. I wouldn't recommend it though, as the aforementioned streaming will make your image-quality suffer big-time.

Let me propose a different solution:
using the cable of the phone in question, you can directly capture the image from the device. The only issue would be bringing the recordings in sync (if that's important). To fix this, you could open up an online clock for example which displays the exact time, so when stitching together the recordings in post, you'll be able to synchronize the recordings.

Comment: Not quite what I need, but thanks for taking the time to answer :D